# HTML 5 pattern validation for text input not working on safari or firefox with iphone

Tags: android, iphone, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have an iphone browser that I'm testing the HTML 5 validation.  I am using safari and Firefox and neither will validate my form input.  I have tested in Firefox and Chrome on my PC and it works.

Is this supported on the IPhone and Android browsers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input name='test1' type='text' placehoder='Test 1' required maxlength='32' pattern='^[0-9\w\s]+'></input>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Android, Safari and Mobile Safari support the pattern attribute, but do not support form validation, so will not prevent an incorrect value from being submitted."

http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/10-pattern.html

It works on Firefox though, see the specs for the pattern attribute:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: I have tried it with Chrome and FF on the w3 page.  I does not work for me, so it must be my computer.  I'll keep searching.

Comment: @mbomb007 Me.  I figured it out.  I expected (I forgot) it to die when entering in the text like keyevent.  You have to hit submit.  Sorry.

Comment: @mbomb007 your link is dead.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich [Archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140701122929/https://blueashes.com/2013/web-development/html5-form-validation-fallback/)